# How to randomly rotate file names between them

Tags: windows, c++, bash, filenames

I have a large group of .wav files (~24 000 in 2 folders). Dialogues. So i want to make these dialogues random. Is there any software that can randomly rename files by using a "table" of these?

Comment: Do you want to rename files to random names? Dou you want to maintain the name translations (i.e. be able to restore the original filenames)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make clear that you are [asking for a software tool](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information), otherwise it's off-topic here.

Comment: How about renaming them 1.wav ... 24000.wav, and then using a random number generator to pick a number between 1 and 24,000 and they play that file?